# . gitlab-ci. yml pipeline run only on one branch

Tags: gitlab-ci

i have  . gitlab-ci. yml file. when i push to stage branch it make stage commands (only stage)  but when i merge to main it's still make "only  stage" command

what i am missing ??

```yaml
variables:
  DOCKER_REGISTRY: 036470204880.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-east-1
  APP_NAME: apiv6
  APP_NAME_STAGE: apiv6-test
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375

publish:
  image: 
    name: amazon/aws-cli
    entrypoint: [""]
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - amazon-linux-extras install docker
    - aws --version
    - docker --version
  script:
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:latest  .
    - aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $DOCKER_REGISTRY
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:latest
    - aws ecs update-service --cluster apiv6 --service apiv6 --force-new-deployment
  only:
    - main



publish:
  image: 
    name: amazon/aws-cli
    entrypoint: [""]
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - amazon-linux-extras install docker
    - aws --version
    - docker --version
  script:
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME_STAGE:latest  .
    - aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $DOCKER_REGISTRY
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME_STAGE:latest
    - aws ecs update-service --cluster apiv6-test --service apiv6-test-service --force-new-deployment


  only:
    - stage
```

Answer (score 0):

Itamar, I believe this is a YAML limitation. See this [GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/31532) as reference.

The problem is that you have two jobs with the same name. But when the YAML file is parsed, you're actually overriding the first job.

Also, from the [official GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/):

> Use unique names for your jobs. If multiple jobs have the same name, only one is added to the pipeline, and it’s difficult to predict which one is chosen

Please, try renaming one of your jobs and test it again.